# Выдаёт ошибку при использовании input

Tags: python, input

Здравствуйте начал изучать программирование и вовремя проверки кода из сайта metanit получаю ошибку. Другой бы наверно забил но я решил что буду основательно браться за весь материал и поэтому хочу знать в чём же проблема. Пишу в visual studio. Язык python.

Код:

```
name = input("Введите имя: ") 
print("Привет", name)
```

Ошибка:
[image: Ошибка при запуске кода]

Comment: смените язык на Английский и попробуйте снова

Comment: @АндрейКуликов да так получилось. Спасибо

Comment: Используйте кодировку UTF-8 в коде. У вас скорее всего cp1251.